# Why does setSinkId does not work with BiquadFilters?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make music player with live ability to change output device (headphones or speakers).
I have working function to change destination device with setSinkId.
I also have working Biquad Filters (low pass, high pass...) and audio processor to generate gain level bars (image below).
[Filter sliders and gain bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HauMV.jpg)

Some of the code (it's a lot).

Setting output device:

```
if (audiooutput_ch1active == 0) {
    if (typeof audiooutput_headphonesid !== "undefined") {
        audiooutput_ch1active = 1;
        await audio_ch1.setSinkId(audiooutput_headphonesid);
        return;
    }
} else if (audiooutput_ch1active == 1) {
    if (typeof audiooutput_speakersid !== "undefined") {
        audiooutput_ch1active = 0;
        await audio_ch1.setSinkId(audiooutput_speakersid);
        return;
    }
}
```

Defining filters:

```
var filter_ch1_lowpass = audioCtx_ch1.createBiquadFilter();  
filter_ch1_lowpass.type = "lowpass";  
filter_ch1_lowpass.frequency.value = 12000;  
var filter_ch1_highpass = audioCtx_ch1.createBiquadFilter();  
filter_ch1_highpass.type = "highpass";  
filter_ch1_highpass.frequency.value = 0;  
var filter_ch1_lowshelf = audioCtx_ch1.createBiquadFilter();  
filter_ch1_lowshelf.type = "lowshelf";  
filter_ch1_lowshelf.frequency.value = 100;  
filter_ch1_lowshelf.gain.value = 0;
```

Connecting filters and processor:

```
audio_ch1.src = path;
source_ch1 = audioCtx_ch1.createMediaElementSource(audio_ch1);
source_ch1.connect(filter_ch1_lowpass);
filter_ch1_lowpass.connect(filter_ch1_highpass);
filter_ch1_highpass.connect(filter_ch1_lowshelf);
filter_ch1_lowshelf.connect(processor_ch1);
filter_ch1_lowshelf.connect(audioCtx_ch1.destination);
processor_ch1.connect(filter_ch1_lowshelf);
```

When I connect filters to my audio context, I can't use setSinkId - Error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation could not be performed and was aborted

When I skip code that connects filters, setSinkId works fine.

Does setSinkId not support audio context filters?

I'm new to JavaScript audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the sink of an `<audio>` element after you did route that `<audio>`'s output to your audio context. The `<audio>` already lost the control over its output, it's now the audio context that has control over it, you thus can't set the sink of the `<audio>` element anymore.

That you can call this method when not using the filter is part of large Chrome bug in the Web Audio API which I believe they're actively working on: basically, they really create the connections only when the audio graph gets connected to a destination.

You could avoid that error to be thrown by creating a `MediaStream` from your `<audio>`, by calling its `captureStream()` method, and then connecting a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` made from that `MediaStream` object to your audio graph. However you'd still only be setting the sink of the input `<audio>`, and not of the one you've been modifying in your audio context.

So instead, what you probably want is to set the sink of the audio context directly.
There is an [active proposal](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audiocontext-setsinkid) to add a `setSinkId()` method on the `AudioContext` interface, latest Chrome Canary does expose it. However it's still a proposal, and AFAICT only Canary exposes it. So in a near future you'll just have to do

```js
audioCtx_ch1.setSinkId(audiooutput_speakersid).catch(handlePossibleError);
```

but for now, you'll need to do some gymnastic by first creating a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` where you'll connect your audio graph, set its `MediaStream` as the `srcObject` of another `<audio>` element on which you'll call `setSinkId()`.

```js
udio_ch1.src = path;
// might be better to use createMediaStreamSource(audio_ch1.captureStream()) anyway here
source_ch1 = audioCtx_ch1.createMediaElementSource(audio_ch1);
source_ch1.connect(filter_ch1_lowpass);
filter_ch1_lowpass.connect(filter_ch1_highpass);
filter_ch1_highpass.connect(filter_ch1_lowshelf);
filter_ch1_lowshelf.connect(processor_ch1);
processor_ch1.connect(filter_ch1_lowshelf);

const outputNode = audioCtx_ch1.createMediaStreamDestination();
filter_ch1_lowshelf.connect(outputNode);
const outputElem = new Audio();
outputElem.srcObject = outputNode.stream;
outputElem.setSinkId(audiooutput_speakersid);
outputElem.play();
```

Comment: okay, I changed my code to what you suggested and now I have 2 audio outputs - one is default audio_ch1 which plays song to default system audio output device and outputElem which plays song with applied filters to device set by sink Id. How do I disable output from first audio element?

Comment: You can mute it (.muted = true)